# how to get iPhone or iPad browser/firmware version in fullscreen mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webkit, mobile-safari

I need to know if `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: scroll;` is available for my webapp, otherwise I get that feature with iScroll.

I'm checking with mootools if the native scrolling overflow is implemented in this way

```
if(Browser.version < 5.1) console.log('fix it with iScroll')
else console.log('the native scrolling is available');
```

The problem: if I save the webapp to the springboard, in fullscreen mode `Browser.version` or `Browser.name` gives me *'0'* or *'unknown'*.

```
if(Browser.version < 5.1 || Browser.version == 0) console.log('fix it with iScroll')
else console.log('the native scrolling is available');
```

The solution above works perfectly, but I don't want to always use iScroll in fullscreen mode on iOS5, because it's not smooth as the native scroll.

How can I know the version of the firmware or if the native scrolling is available in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that something is broken with mootools 1.4.0.
To be sure if you're running ios5 (browser or fullscreen mode):

```
(/CPU OS 5_0/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? console.log('iOS5') : console.log('not iOS5');
```